# How to 100% set a default view and sort order for all folders in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, sorting

Now, I'm experienced with SE. Questions similar to this will have been asked before.

**HOWEVER**, (notice the bold style) this is a question about displaying a list of files with columns for name, date, and size on your computer. What that means is that there are no exceptions. When I open any folder or file requester window, the files are displayed in this Details-esque mode regardless of content, and sorted by last modified date, descending.

I'm asking this question to know if this is in any way achievable on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: There are no exceptions per volume or disk partition perhaps for whatever folders you open with Windows Explorer in particular? So if you setup a view for one folder on the "C" drive then you want it to be the default view for all others you open on that particular drive? I think there are some gotcha's with this going across  disk partitions, volumes, drive letters, etc. even if all NTFS partitions.

Comment: I mean the gotcha's per the duplicate answers you see to this question already about saving folder views to all folders. .... if it's not working 100% of the time as you expect, it could be due to these reasons or even perhaps security permissions so those are things to consider as to why it may not be applying to all folders. Consider created a script or using shortcut keys to setup and define the view for any folders you open that it's not defined as such when apply folder views to all folders to have a quick and speedy way to deal with the exceptions/anamolies.